# How to add multiple files to py2app?

Tags: python, import, package, py2app

I have a python script which makes a GUI. When a button 'Run' is pressed in this GUI it runs a function from an imported package (which I made) like this

```
from predictmiP import predictor
class MiPFrame(wx.Frame):
    [...]
    def runmiP(self, event):
         predictor.runPrediction(self.uploadProtInterestField.GetValue(), self.uploadAllProteinsField.GetValue(), self.uploadPfamTextField.GetValue(), \
                   self.edit_eval_all.Value, self.edit_eval_small.Value, self.saveOutputField)
```

When I run the GUI directly from python it all works well and the program writes an output file. However, when I make it into an app, the GUI starts but when I press the button nothing happens. predictmiP does get included in build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/python2.7-standalone/app/collect/, like all the other imports I'm using (although it is empty, but that's the same as all the other imports I have).

How can I get multiple python files, or an imported package to work with py2app?

my setup.py:

"""
This is a setup.py script generated by py2applet

Usage:
    python setup.py py2app
"""

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['mip3.py']
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {'argv_emulation': True}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

---

edit:

It looked like it worked, but it only works for a little. From my GUI I call

```
 blast.makeBLASTdb(self.uploadAllProteinsField.GetValue(), 'allDB')

 # to test if it's working
 dlg = wx.MessageDialog( self, "werkt"+self.saveOutputField, "werkt", wx.OK)
 dlg.ShowModal() # Show it
 dlg.Destroy() # finally destroy it when finished.
```

blast.makeBLASTdb looks like this:

```
def makeBLASTdb(proteins_file, database_name):  
    subprocess.call(['/.'+os.path.realpath(__file__).rstrip(__file__.split('/')[-1])+'blast/makeblastdb', '-in', proteins_file, '-dbtype', 'prot', '-out', database_name])
```

This function gets called, makeblastdb which I call through subprocess does output a file. However, the program does not continue,

```
dlg = wx.MessageDialog( self, "werkt"+self.saveOutputField, "werkt", wx.OK)
dlg.ShowModal() # Show it
```

in the next lines never gets executed.

Comment: Where is your setup.py ? What is this predictmiP module/package ? Pure Python or what ?

Comment: it is pure python. I will edit my question to include my setup.py

Comment: Reduce the problem to a self-contained example for more accurate help.

Comment: Yeah I'll need to make a new question for that. The importing of packages works now, thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

py2app (or rather, setup.py) doesn't magically include files, just because you import them in your application code.

From your description it's not quite clear to me where the predictmiP.py file is located, where the mip3.py file is located, where the setup.py file is located, and how the rest of the directory tree looks.

So, a few general notes on packaging Python files (see also http://docs.python.org/2.7/distutils/index.html). If you just have a few files, you can list them explicitly:

```
setup(
    py_modules=['file1', 'file2']
)
```

This would include `file1.py` and `file2.py`. If you have lots of files, that gets tedious, of course, so you can tell setup.py to include all Python files it finds, like so:

```
setup(
    package='example',
)
```

This expects a directory named `example`, containing an `__init__.py`, and will include all Python files found there.

If you have a different directory layout, e.g. a `src` directory containing the Python files, set it like this:

```
setup(
    package='example',
    package_dir={'': 'src'}
)
```

This expects a directory `src/example`, and includes the Python files below there.

Comment: py2app does "magically" include modules and packages after you run `python setup.py py2app` to construct a bundle. It doesn't include in the setup.py, but should in the final bundle. But I'm not exactly sure if did he build a bundle or not.

Comment: The adding the python package is working, I'm having a different problem with the app not continuing after a command line tool is finished, but I'll need to make a different question for that. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 7):

Since your setup.py is not provided, I will guess it does not resemble something like:

```
from setuptools import setup

OPTIONS = {'packages' : ['predictmiP']}

setup(app=someapp.py, options={'py2app' : OPTIONS},
      setup_requires=['py2app'])
```

Or maybe you are looking for `OPTIONS['includes']` ? Or maybe `OPTIONS['frameworks']` ?

Comment: that did it.. thanks! so I have to add every package I want to import to the packages list?

Comment: Until you added your setup.py, I had no idea you were using py2app. Then after I saw you were using py2app, I got a little confused because it should detect imported packages/modules and include them in the bundle. Do you get the error when running the bundle generated by `python setup.py py2app` ? It could be a py2app bug. On the other hand, I find this to be a good thing in general simply because I prefer to directly specify what I'm using rather than wasting time with dependency trackers.

Comment: No I don't, the program just starts up but when I press the run button it doesn't do anything. Now that I use the package option it does